# Change visibility of footer without display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to make my footer which point to a SharePoint list displayed in an iframe visible after the content in the iframe has finished rendering.

I need to keep the footer placeholder on the page so **display:none and then show using js is not going to work**.

Here is the code:

```js
$("iframe").ready(function() {
    $(".fatFooter").show();
});
```

```css
.fatFooter {
     visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fatFooter" style="width:100%; background-color:#37424a;">
 <div style="height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="border: 0; width: 100%; /*height: 200px;*/">
   <iframe style="width:100%; padding:5px 0; 
   margin-left:0px; overflow:hidden !important;" src="http://aol.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="370px">
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="width:100%; height:180px; background-color:#23292e; text-align:center;">
  <div style="height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="border: 0; width: 100%; /*height: 200px;*/">
   <iframe style="width:100%; padding:20px 0; 
   margin-left:0px; overflow:hidden !important;" src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="180px">
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the [tag:jquery] tag since you seem to be using it. If you do not want answers to use jQuery, feel free to [edit] your question and remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("iframe").ready(function() {
    $(".fatFooter").css({visibility: "visible"});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyway to add about a 2 second delay? I am just catching the tail end of some load but much closer then I was...

Comment: $('.fatfooter').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);

Comment: That didn't work for me. Here is what I am using. `$("iframe").ready(function() { 
 $('.fatfooter').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000); 
});`

Comment: Fixed it... The class is supposed to be .fatFooter - With capital F... Works great Thanks!

Comment: I assume you wanted a 2 second fade in. If you want an actual 2 second delay, use: setTimeout(function(){$(".fatFooter").css({visibility: "visible"})}, 2000);